# WebRTC: IceCandidates aren't gathered in Chrome/Edge

Tags: webrtc

I am developing a conference application using WebRTC and I have one issue which is pretty strange. More exactly, as the title says, onicecandidate doesn't gather all the needed candidates, or more exactly gathers only the null one, then the gathering state becomes completed. This happens only for the remote peer and depending on the PC I use in either Chrome or Edge (Chromium), on one PC working in Chrome well but not on Edge and in another working on Edge well but on in Chrome.

The icecandidates of the peer who creates the offer are gathered correctly, they are sent and the remote peer is setting them, only the remote peer never gathers any, except for a null one.

I configured the rtcpeerconnection to use a stun server from google (I am running on localhost for now) but nothing changed. Are there any special steps I must take to make everything work well in both browsers?

EDIT: I noticed this problem because the track that is sent by ontrack function to the remote peers isn't playing, the video.play() promise in the remote peer only staying forever in pending, neither continuing further nor crashing. The difference that I noticed between the browsers in which it works and the ones it doesn't is the lack of ICE candidates sent by remote, in places where all were sent the video playing remotely also.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to set remote description before create answer?

As you know, exchanging sdp is 'negotiation'.

So when remote peer creates own answer sdp, remote peer have to set other peer's sdp.

Like this:

1) Peer A - Create Offer (offer sdp)

2) Peer A - Set Local Description (offer sdp)

3) Peer B - Set Remote Description (offer sdp)

4) Peer B - Create Answer (answer sdp)

5) Peer B - Set Local Description (answer sdp)

6) Peer A - Set Remote Description (answer sdp)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I am doing it. I generate the offer, set is as local as soon as generated, send it to remote where it is set as remote description as soon as received, generate answer and send it to caller where is set as local. That's why the behavior I have is strange, in some browsers and PCs it works, in some it does not. One thing that is sure is that the connection and the tracks are always sent, just not the remote ice candidates.

Comment: Hmm.. That's weird. I think you already added webrtc-adapter.
Could you check webrtc-internals in chrome?

Comment: Yes, WebRTC adapter is imported in the component which uses WebRTC and in polyfills.ts (using Angular). Both Chrome and Edge say in webrtc-internals that they read stats from "standardized (promise-based) getStats() API.

Comment: Can I check your source code? If can not, refer [my source code](https://github.com/verycosy/webRTC/blob/master/server/public/script.js). That repository is simple project for check webrtc APIs. I think webrtc connection steps in your source code are not clearly called.

Comment: I cloned your repository, and tested. But it works well on Chrome-Chrome and Chrome-FireFox. I use MacOS, so I can't use Edge. It didn't work only on Edge?

Comment: That's the thing, on one of my laptops it works on Edge, and in another it works on Chrome, but never on both, for some reason... No error is given at all, I just don't receive the candidates.

Comment: Could you check answer sdp on Edge? I heard if some attributes(ice-ufrag, ice-pwd, fingerprint, candidate) are not exists in answer sdp, Edge browser will not send any packets. So I recommend compare SDP on Chrome and Edge. And your testing environment(laptop, PC) is same network, right?